# I have .js inside an iframe. Can't find element

Tags: javascript, python-3.x, selenium

I am doing scraping with python and selenium.
Trying to access a table inside an iframe.

1. Page source section as below:

   ```
   <div id="pageContentDiv">
   <iframe frameborder="0" id="content" name="content" src="emxBlank.jsp" width="100%" height="100%"></iframe>
   <iframe class="hidden-frame" id="hiddenFrame" name="hiddenFrame" src="emxBlank.jsp"></iframe>
   <iframe class="hidden-frame" id="integrationsFrame" name="integrationsFrame" src="../integrations/emxIntegrations.jsp"></iframe>
   <iframe class="hidden-frame" id="appletFrame" name="appletFrame" src="emxBlank.jsp"></iframe>
   <iframe class="hidden-frame" id="ClipboardCollection" name="ClipboardCollection" src="emxClipboardCollection.jsp"></iframe>
   </div>
   ```
2. While using firefox inspector, it should be

   ```
   <div id="pageContentDiv" style="top: 0px;">
    <div id="divPageHead" class="page-head">
     <form method="post">
      <div class="toolbar-subcontainer">
       <table>
        <tbody><tr>
         <td class="page-title">
          <h2>Part XXX XXXXXXXXX AA: BOM XXXXXXX</h2>
         </td>
         <td class="functions">
       <table>
       <tbody><tr>
       <td class="progress-indicator"><div id="imgProgressDiv" style="visibility: hidden;"></div></td>
       </tr></tbody></table>
   </td>
   </tr>
   </tbody></table>
   </div>





   <script type="text/javascript">
   function getTopAccessFrame() {
   var oTop = this;
   while(oTop && oTop.parent != oTop && oTop.name != "mxPortletContent" ){
   try{
       var doc = oTop.parent.test = "temp";
   }catch(e){
       break;
   }

   oTop = oTop.parent;}

   try{
   while(oTop.name != "mxPortletContent" && oTop.opener && oTop.opener.top){
       var docOpenerTop = oTop.opener.top.test = "temp";
       oTop = oTop.opener.top
   }}catch(e){}

   return oTop;}
   </script>

   <script type="text/javascript">
   var topAccessFrame = getTopAccessFrame();
   if(typeof topAccessFrame.emxUIConstants != "object"){
       document.write("<scri" + "pt language=\"JavaScript\" type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"../common/emxUIConstantsJavaScriptInclude.jsp\"></scr" + "ipt>");
   }else{
       var emxUIConstants = topAccessFrame.emxUIConstants;
   }
   </script>
   <script language="javascript" src="scripts/emxUICalendar.js"</script>
   <script language="JavaScript" src="...></script>

   <div class="toolbar-container" id="divToolbarContainer">
   <div id="divToolbar" class="toolbar-frame"><div class="toolbar">
   </div></div>
   </div>



   </form>
   </div><!-- /#pageHeadDiv -->
   <div id="divPageBody" style="top: 55px;">
   <iframe name="portalDisplay" src="emxPortalDisplay.jsp?portal=ENCPartEBOMPortal&amp;header=emxEngineeringCentral.ObjectPortal.PartEBOMHeader&amp;HelpMarker=emxhelppartebompv&amp;objectId=51758.28388.51328.17028&amp;suiteKey=EngineeringCentral&amp;StringResourceFileId=emxEngineeringCentralStringResource&amp;SuiteDirectory=engineeringcentral&amp;treeLabel=XXXX" border="0" width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0"></iframe>
   </div>
   <div></div></div>
   ```

Detail about my question:

1. I don't know which iframe should I switch to.
2. Once switch into the iframe, I'm still getting .js code only but not any elements.
3. I'm using Firefox. Is it causing the issue?

I have already tried iframe switch as

```
iframe=driver.find_element_by_name("ClipboardCollection")
driver.switch_to.frame(iframe)
```

Not solving my problem.

Comment: Which element you want to interact?

Comment: @YosuvaA final result should be under iframe with id="content". It will call javascript and generate a chain of divs frameset and iframe as container for the final element.

Comment: Is your table present inside ```<iframe frameborder="0" id="content"> ``` this?

Comment: Is your table present inside ```<iframe frameborder="0" id="content"> ``` this? If yes try switching to this iframe and try to interact with table

Comment: Can i get you application url? So that i can have a look.